# How to Facebook login without opening Facebook app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I recently installed the app "mapstr" and when you choose Facebook login, you don't go through the Facebbok app, you just accept the permissions through a kind of alertView :

[image]

It's written in French and it says : "mapstr" wants to access your public profile and your friends list.

When I tap OK, I am just logged with Facebook : no app switching !

How do they do that ? 
(I am developping in Swift 2.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Mapstr founder ;)
It's a loginBehavior option in Facebook LoginManager (in iOS SDK) which is the "FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount" (you also have the app option and the web option)
If a user has configure his face boo account on its iPhone, the SDK will use it, if not it will try the app, and then the web.
The only drawback is that if the system account exists but is misconfigured it failed...
Sebastien

Comment: The answer couldn't come from a better source !
Congrats for the founds you've raised ! We may meet soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its using the facebook Credentials saved in your iPhone settings to login through facebook. You will need to use accounts framework for that. Below is the sample code for the same.

```
-(void)facebook
{
ACAccountStore  *accountStore;
accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kFACEBOOK_APPID,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
     if (granted)
     {
         [self afterPermissionGranted:accountStore accountType:FBaccountType];
     }
     else
     {
         //Fail gracefully...
         NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
         });
     }
 }];
}
-(void)afterPermissionGranted:(ACAccountStore  *)accountStore accountType:(ACAccountType *)FBaccountType{

NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
//it will always be the last object with single sign on
if ([accounts count] == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Other Facebook Account Found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
else{
    ACAccount *facebookAccount;
    facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
    ACAccountCredential *facebookCredential = [facebookAccount credential];
    NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];
    NSLog(@"FAT: %@", accessToken);
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:nil];
    request.account = facebookAccount;


    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error)
        {
            NSDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSDictionary *errorPart = [list objectForKey:@"error"];
            NSString *errorsubCode =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[errorPart valueForKey:@"error_subcode"]];
            if (![errorsubCode isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
                });
            }
            else{
                NSString *globalmailID   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list objectForKey:@"email"]];
                NSLog(@"global mail : %@",globalmailID);


                NSString *fbname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list objectForKey:@"name"]];
                NSLog(@"fname %@",fbname);
                ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [facebookAccount credential];
                NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];

                [self saveDataFromFacebook:error user:list accessToken:(NSString *)accessToken];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
            //attempt to revalidate credentials
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self endProgressBar];

        });
    }];
}
}
```

Please remove the extra code. Feel free to ask any queries.